# How might one most efficiently calculate contingent values?

Tags: vba, performance, userform

Suppose that I have 10 values n_1, n_2, ... n_10 and that given any 1 of these value, the other 9 can be calculated. Let f_i(n_j) be the function that calculates the value n_i using the values of n_j (where i != j). These functions are relatively simple (i.e. contain no more than a few exponential functions or powers).

In terms of the functions used, what would be the most efficient way of creating a program to calculate the other 9 values in n_1, ..., n_10 given the 1 that is initially known?

Would the best option be to minimize the number of functions used (and thus minimize the number of lines of code), or to create a function defining every single mapping?

For example, would it be most efficient to use only the 18 functions

```
f_1(n_2), f_1(n_3), ..., f_1(n_10)        [1]
f_2(n_1), f_3(n_1), ..., f_10(n_1)        [2]
```

And then, for whatever input is provided by the user, the value of n_1 may be calculated by using the relevant function in line [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBXA1.png), from which every other value of intererest may be calculated using functions from line [2]?

Or would it be better to define all 90 mappings, and so that only a single function (rather than 2 functions) must be called to calculate each of the 9 other values?

**Edit: The specific result that I am trying to achieve is as follows...**

I am currently using VBA, with a user form of the following format:

[image: form]

The conversion frequency is a required field (so lets just say, for example, that it is always equal to 2 and forget about it). I want to use on change events so that whenever the user changes any of the 6 fields below the conversion frequency field, the other 5 fields are auto-filled with the correct value. However, since the user need only update any **one** out of six fields, with the other 5 fields being calculated from this, we will require 6^6-6 = 30 different functions to do these calculations. We will thus end up with a lot of repetitive code.

My question regards the best practices to follow when working with a form where one of many inputs may be provided, and all other fields must be updated as a result of the input provided and its value.

Or, equivalently, is there a way to update all fields when the value of one field changes? Can this be done without the number of lines of code required increasing exponentially as the number of fields increases?

Comment: I think this question is too abstract. It sounds like you are trying to explain your solution before you give details of the problem. Do you have a real example of what you are trying to accomplish? I have a feeling the optimal solution depends a great deal on the specific problem you are tackling.

Comment: Hi, cheers for the comment. I have updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are grossly overthinking this. Think of this in terms of the formulas you need; which I think are 6. 6 functions that take 5 inputs each:

```
calculateEIR(nominalInterestRate, ForceOfInterest, DiscountFactor, EffectiveDiscountRate, NominalDiscountRate)
calculateNIR(EffectiveInterestRate, ForceOfInterest, DiscountFactor, EffectiveDiscountRate, NominalDiscountRate)
' and so on...
```

The event handlers, and the code to calculate the values are their own thing. Your onchange event handlers simply need to call the correct methods; this is 6 event handlers calling 5 methods each, so 11 functions if you want to keep count. It's a lot of copypasta. For example:

```
sub textEffectiveInterestRate_onchange()
    Me.textNominalInterstRate.value = calculateNIR(Me.textEffectiveInterestRate.value, Me.textForceOfInterest.value, etc...)
    Me.textForceOfInterest.value = calculateForceOfInterest(Me.textEffectiveInterestRate.value, Me.textNominalInterstRate.value, etc...)
    ' And every other function aside from calculateEIR()
end sub
```

I am unsure about the specifics of how you are changing all the values based on a change in the others (since I don't know the formulas), but in general, you should not in any way need 30 functions...